# SpringSource Tool suite: How to get my project to run on Tomcat 5.5 / Java 5?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.0.RELEASE.  I want to configure my project to use a run configuration that is a Tomcat 5.5 server using JRE 1.5 (I'm on Mac 10.6.6).  I'm having trouble doing this.  When configuring my Tomcat 5 server, I set the JRE runtime to be 1.5 …

http://screencast.com/t/MugGt8bE9p

But when I try and add my project to the new server configuration, I get this error hen I click on my project …

```
Tomcat version 5.5 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 Web modules
```

Here is what the screen looks like -- http://screencast.com/t/WcmB0DjuTCaK .  Does anyone know how I can get past this error or how I can get my project to run on Tomcat 5.5 using Java 1.5?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, the issue is not your version of Java, but the version of J2EE libraries. Make sure that you did not include any J2EE 5 libraries and that the third party libraries that you use are fine with older J2EE libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the J2EE version.In the project facets>Dynamic web module> version. you can change the version here.